# Create 6 Distinctive Random Numbers

Tags: flutter, dart, random, non-repetitive

Create 6 Distinctive Random Numbers using Flutter and Dart to make an app. Where these 6 different numbers don't repeat themselves when they are randomize

Although I used this

```dart
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  List<int> values = [];

  while (values.length < 6) {
    int randomValue = Random().nextInt(50);

    if (!values.contains(randomValue)) {
      values.add(randomValue);
    }
  }

  print('Randomized values: $values');
}
```

But I can't display it on the text widget in my app

And also I tried creating an  elevated button so that when I click it, the figures change

Comment: Focus on your problem and show the code where you try to display it in the text widget. We're not going to solve this problem for you. Check and correct your question before posting. You haven't accepted any one of the answers on your previous questions.

Comment: Is your problem related to using random numbers? If not, please don't use tags that don't have any impact on your question.

Comment: It has because I want to create random numbers in such a way that it doesn't repeat itself

Comment: You're creating the random numbers. Your question says you're having problems displaying on the text widget, which has nothing to do with whether the numbers are random or not.

Comment: I have,3 problems. Creating,6 random numbers in a way they don't repeat themselves, Displaying it on the text widget And creating a button so that when it is clicked it would randomize the figures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Set` instead of `List`.

```dart
void main() {
  Set<int> values = {};

  while (values.length < 6) {
    int randomValue = Random().nextInt(50);

    if (!values.contains(randomValue)) {
      values.add(randomValue);
    }
  }

  print('Randomized values: $values');
}
```

This can take quite a time based on random generation.

Comment: The expected number of iterations is ~9.31 to generate 6 values out of 50. That's hardly "quite a time".

Comment: It's simpler to just add generated numbers without testing contains, and do it until the set size suffices.

Comment: I multiplied when I should have added. The correct expectation is ~6.32 iterations to generate the 6 values. That's effectively a 5% penalty due to the chance of collisions.

Comment: Yea, didn't notice this unnecessary part , thanks @RandalSchwartz

Answer (score 0):

your code looks like pure Dart code.

And your code is just fine to generate the 6 random numbers and put it into an array.

If you have Flutter code around, you can just quickly do print the array in a `Text()` widget doing this:

```
Text(values.toString())
```

An entire class in Flutter using your same code could be:

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class YourClass extends StatelessWidget {
  const YourClass({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<int> values = [];
    while (values.length < 6) {
      int randomValue = Random().nextInt(50);
      if (!values.contains(randomValue)) {
        values.add(randomValue);
      }
    }
    print('Randomized values: $values');

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
          body: Text(values.toString())
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh really nice. Let me try it out. Okay another issue am having is putting a button so that when you click it, the figures randomize